# Enable FastCGI on Litespeed

Tags: .htaccess, fastcgi, litespeed

How would I enable my Litespeed server to process .fcgi files using a FastCGI module? I tried setting the handler to `fcgid-script` already but that doesn't work.

Syntax:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
Options +ExecCGI
```

Just to avoid confusion, I am **not** trying to run PHP or Ruby scripts through FastCGI. I want to run raw assembly that is compiled to work with FastCGI. (I can confirm the code works, have tested on Apache already)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but perhaps it will help someone. The best way to do this is going to be to set up a script handler and external application in LSWS's settings. Check out [this page](http://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php?id=litespeed_wiki:how_do_i_set_up_an_external_application) for reference.

Essentially:

1. Go into the WebAdmin console > External App > Add
2. Select FastCGI Application
3. Name the application and set other settings, the most important being where the backend FCGI script processor is located
4. Save it
5. Create a script handler (WebAdmin console > Script Handler > Add)
6. In the script handler, set .fcgi files to go to the FastCGI external application you just created.